# Prove that $|x|\to | l |$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ X= l$. How to prove that $|X|\to|l|$ ?
I started with: 
Given  $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\ K(\epsilon)$ is an element of natural number such that $|X-l|<\epsilon$ for all n>$\ K(\epsilon)$

$|X-l|<\epsilon$
By tiangle inequalities,$|X-l|<|X|+|l|$.
I do not know how to proceed.Is it correct?

Comment: Now, think about converse. Is converse true?

Comment: Do you mean that I'm given  $|X|\to|l|$ and have to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ X= l$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use important inequality:
For same $\epsilon>0$ that u choosed

$||X|-|L||\leq|X-L|<\epsilon$ for all $n>K(\epsilon)$

Hence,$|X|\to|L|$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**: Use the reverse triangle inequality $$\bigl||x|-|y|\bigr| \le |x-y|. $$